# Restrict Docker containers to the UNIX user that runs it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, multiple-users

I'm opening my Docker server to more users and I'm facing this problem:  when I do `docker ps` with a user that is not the author of the container (e.g `paul`), I see all the containers and can interact with it (stop, kill, etc), and it's not what I would like.

What could be a good way to restrict containers to their original user and then not have access to all of them on the server, so when I do `docker ps` I see just the containers ran by `paul` and not `jack` or `jess`?

All my containers are started with different users, none with root.

Answer (score 0):

1. Anyone with access to Docker is equivalent to `root`.

   Consider that I can run something like this:

   ```
   docker run -v /:/host alpine
   ```

   Now I can edit **any file** on your host with root privileges.
2. Docker is fundamentally not a multi-user tool. Either you trust everybody, or you use virtualization to give everyone their own individual Docker instance, or you front Docker with some sort of API proxy that limits the things people can do.

   Because it's not a multi-user tool, Docker doesn't really keep track of the user that started a container, so there's no way to filter on that information.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't had this vision in mind. What could be a solution with the ideas you mentioned? Is there any tutorial about this that I could try? I'm not super experienced with this concept. Thanks!

Comment: Access to docker do NOT require any root previleges!! All users who have been assigned the group "docker" can administer docker containers.

Comment: @F.Madsen I thought so too. But there is no way to create groups to manage certain containers right? That would be awesome tho

Comment: All users who have been assigned the group "docker" can edit the host's `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/sudoers` files.  A "docker" group is absolutely 100% equivalent to root permission on the host.

Comment: @F.Madsen I didn't say access **requires** root privileges, I said it **grants** root privileges.

Comment: Well it is an intresting question. Dont confuse the dockerroot and the docker group. Please create a group docker and assign that to users operating the docker daemon. That will NOT give the user write access to system files, but give you "root" access to the docker daemon only. Also to avoid root access within the container you can use the USER directive in the Dockerfile so set an alternative running user.

Comment: @F.Madsen It will *absolutely* give the user write access to system files.  You can always run `docker run -u root -v /:/host anycontainer sh' and have (a) a root shell with (b) write access to all files on the host system.  You cannot prevent this with a `USER` directive in the Dockerfile because the `-u root` on the command line takes precedence. This is a basic fact of how Docker operates and it is irresponsible to tell people that "access to docker" is any different from "root on your system".